# Implementing an Optimization problem using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement an Optimization problem using matlab

[image]

Where N=100 , M=(N-1/k) and L=50.

```
N=100;
L = 50;
for K= 101:1:1000
M = (N-1)/K;
R=@(x) -((1./x(2)).*(N- (x(1).*M)-((min ( N./(L.*x(2)), K)-x(1))*(max(0,N-(L.*x(2).*x(1)))))/(x(1)+(min ( N./(L.*x(2)), K)-x(2)))) - (max(0,N-(L.*K*x(2)))));
LB = [1 1];
b=1:min((ceil(N/L)), K) ;
UB = [min((ceil(N./L)), K) ((N./(L*b))) ];
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point'); % run interior-point algorithm
[xopt, vopt] = fmincon(R,1,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options); 
v(K) = -vopt;
end 
 plot(101:1000,v,'v-','LineWidth',2);
xlabel('Number of Users (K)');
ylabel('Delivery Rate (R)');
```

The following error appears:

> ```
> Warning: Length of lower bounds is > length(x); ignoring extra bounds. 
> > In checkbounds (line 27)
>   In fmincon (line 318)
>   In R1 (line 19) 
> Warning: Length of upper bounds is > length(x); ignoring extra bounds. 
> > In checkbounds (line 41)
>   In fmincon (line 318)
>   In R1 (line 19) 
> Index exceeds array bounds.
>
> Error in
> R1>@(x)-((1./x(2)).*(N-(x(1).*M)-((min(N./(L.*x(2)),K)-x(1))*(max(0,N-(L.*x(2).*x(1)))))/(x(1)+(min(N./(L.*x(2)),K)-x(2))))-(max(0,N-(L.*K*x(2)))))
>
> Error in fmincon (line 546)
>       initVals.f = feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});
>
> Error in R1 (line 19)
> [xopt, vopt] = fmincon(R,1,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options);
>
> Caused by:
>     Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.
> ```

The output graph should be the one shown here:

[image]

(the lower bound curve)

Comment: This seems to be the problem: `b=1:min((ceil(N/L)), K) ;`. Did you mean to use the colon there?

Comment: Also, it probably doesn't really matter, but you're missing a `.` before the `*` in one place in the definition of `R`.

Answer (score 0):

## Couples of mistakes

- First, the initial guess should be an 1D array of **length 2**, kindly
  replace `1` by `[1, 1]`
- Better initialize the variable `v` first , it will speed up your
  computation
- The most important is the upper bound of `l`, as you can see it
  depends on `s` and it's in the denominator, consider it as non linear
  constraint then set `UB = []` You will need to include **nonlcon** into
  `fmincon`

## The code is as follow

```
N=100;
L = 50;
t = 101:1:1000;
le = length(t);
v = zeros(1, le);

for K= 100:1:1000
M = (N-1)/K;
R = @(x) -(1./(x(1))).*(N-x(1).*((N-1)./K)-((min(ceil(N./(L.*x(2))), K)).*...
      max(N -L.*x(1).*x(2), 0))./((x(1) +(min(ceil(N./(L.*x(2))), K))))...
      -(max(N - K.*L.*x(2), 0)));
LB = [1 1];

options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point');
[xopt, vopt] = fmincon(R,[1, 1],[],[],[],[],LB,[],...
    @(x)nonlincon(x(1), x(2),N, L, K ),options); 
v(K-101+1) = -vopt;

end 
plot(101:1000,v,'v-','LineWidth',2);
xlabel('Number of Users (K)');
ylabel('Delivery Rate (R)');

function [c, ceq] = nonlincon(s, l,N, L, K )

    c(1) = l -N./(L.*s);
    c(2) = s - min((ceil(N./L)), K) ;
    ceq = [];
    
end
```